# How to dispatch actions in any function such as error handler?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I do have so many axios calls for which i have written the error handling codes in the respective catch blocks, but what i need is to define a generic error handler for all the error in a separate file and also to dispatch the actions as per the error in order to change the store state.

I have tried to dispatch the action but dispatch is not binded as in action creators we bind it manually but here i haven't binded in with dispatch anywhere

```
handleErrors: () => dispatch => {
        alert("error function called");
        dispatch({type: "HELLO"});
    }
```

I want to use dispatch in this function that is not connected to redux

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to the `store` in order to dispatch actions - in components this is typically done with `connect` but if you are outside of react components you can import the store from wherever you are creating it and then call `store.dispatch({type: "HELLO"});` directly.